# Enabling Highlight On Click for jQuery Map Highlighting

Tags: jquery, plugins, highlight

I am making diagrams using the jQuery Highlight Plugin 
(http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/) and I currently have the diagram that is clickable and loading content based on the area you are clicking on (like simple tabs).

However, I need the map to highlight on click and disable any other highlighted areas. Right now, I can make the area highlight on click, but not disable any existing highlights. I'd also like to have the diagram switch the content on hover, but that isn't as important right now as the highlight on click.

I have my current version up for a demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/keith/PVpgK/

or the fullscreen result:
http://jsfiddle.net/keith/PVpgK/embedded/result/

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the other areas and turn off the alwayson to have the last click unhighlight on a new click.  Try something like this:

```
  //map clicks
   $(".tabs area").click(function(){

       //AREAS LOOP:
       $(".tabs area").each(function(){
           var d = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
           if(d.alwaysOn == true){
             d.alwaysOn = false;  
           }
         });

//DISPLAY CURRENT LI FUNCTION:
$('.tabs area').mouseover(function(){

     var thisTarget = $(this).attr("href");

    if(thisTarget){      
        $('#test').innerHTML = thisTarget;  
    }
     $(this).parents(".tabs").find('area.current').removeClass('current');

     $(this).addClass('current');

     $(this).parents(".tabs").nextAll(".tab-content").children(":visible").fadeOut(1, function() {
         $(thisTarget).fadeIn("fast");
     });

});
   //This block is what creates highlighting by trigger the "alwaysOn",
   var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
   data.alwaysOn = true;  //NOTICE I MADE THIS ALWAYS TRUE
   $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
   //there is also "neverOn" in the docs, but not sure how to get it to work


   if ($(this).hasClass("current") == false)
   {
       var thisTarget = $(this).attr("href");

       $(this).parents(".tabs").find('area.current').removeClass('current');

       $(this).addClass('current');

       $(this).parents(".tabs").nextAll(".tab-content").children(":visible").fadeOut(1, function() {
           $(thisTarget).fadeIn("fast");
       });

   }
   return false;
  });
```

Comment: @wajiw if I wanted to show content on mouseover, but not have it "stick" until it was clicked, how could I add that to the mouseover functionality?

Comment: If you notice when you click on each area, it switched to the content that is associate with that area. I was trying to have the content change on hover as well as on click, so the user could see the different content, and then click to make it "stick"...does that make sense?

Comment: So you want to show the li that corresponds to the hovered element? I'm not sure, let me take a look at that.

Comment: Right, show the li that corresponds to the hovered element, but then if you click it stays on that content (just like it does in your code above...thanks again for that)

Comment: You have to add another mouseover to your code that updates the li elements separately.  I updated my code to show a function that does that under 'DISPLAY CURRENT LI FUNCTION'

Comment: @wajiw I was just trying to make the center area highlight first and then pulsate or fade in/out to let the user know they can interact. I can have the center area highlight on load, but I tried animating opacity on toggling a fade, but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="img" usemap="#map">    

<map name="map">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
 <area shape="poly" coords="[yourCoords]" alt="img" href="javascript:void(0);" class="punto">
</map>
```

JS Code

```
$(function(){
   $('.map').maphilight({
       fillColor: 'ff0000',
       fillOpacity:0.4,
       stroke:false,
       neverOn:true
   });

   $('.punto').click(function(){
       var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
       data.alwaysOn=true;
       $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');;
   });
})
```

Comment: Hi :) thanks for super saver code. Can you please add a code so we can toggle between map areas .i.e. when one area is selected the other should be unselected

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would be to add a class on click and remove it when clicking the next location. After adding the class you can manipulate. That way if you have hundreds or thousands of areas (as my map does) the page doesn't lock up while trying to cycle through each one.

The following link takes you to an answer that explains this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8397900/1101054