# "Always on " jquery command

Tags: javascript, jquery

recently i'm working on a project to make an interactive directory map for a mall without using flash, because  they need to access from mobile devices.

but i have issue with jquery , i'm using custom java commands with jquery map highlight. which i use to target my mapcoords.

Method is invoked when someone clicks either on the map or the list below, it'll highlight the map and it'll show the information on right side.

My problem is when somebody clickd another shop from the list or from the map it won't clear the previous highlighted block and the previous one keeps highlighting, it doesn't matter how many time you click.

what i need is to refine my code such that when somebody clicks the 2nd link it will automatically clear the previous one.

anybody can see my demo file under below link
http://www.pad10.com/testsities/directorymap/

i'll appreciate if somebody help me with this

Comment: this has nothing to do with Java, it's just Javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow .. this is a Question and Answer site for programmers - please take some time to read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - questions that include some code that highlight the problem are better answered

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't turn off the highlight for currently selected area when clicking on another.

Place this:

```
$('.selected').data('maphilight', {alwaysOn: false}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
```

in your `salhia.js`, in the `.mapclick` click handler:

```
$('.mapclick').click(function(){
    $('.selected').data('maphilight', {alwaysOn: false}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');

    $('.mapclick').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var shop = '.shopdetails#' + $(this).attr('shop');
    var htmlCode = $(shop).html();

    $('.shopinfo').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $('.shopinfo .shopdetails').html(htmlCode);
        $('.shopinfo').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Dear Socha, thanks for your answer, i placed your code on .mapclick handler but still not working, i'm new to java scripting so bare with me, if your can copy my script with your edit version, that will be great.

Comment: Dear Socha, thanks again for your quick reply, but i'm beginning to see where my problem is , i have class called "selected" hooked to a mapclick, but the problem is the hilight option comes from the "jquery.maphilight.js" file, my css is not effecting the select state on the map which will not work with the above code you have given me before even the 2 "$('.mapclick').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');"
js codes i put is useless for this situation. i would appreciate if you have any other ideas.

Comment: @user1083175 Yes, `selected` class doesn't change the highlights placed by jquery.maphilight.js. Nevertheless, you can use it in jquery selectors to select previously clicked shop, and remove its 'alwaysOn' option - which is what my code does. Have you tried it?

Comment: Dear Socha, i have use the code same as you given me , but still the when i select the 1st one then i select the 2nd one first 1 is still selected. it's not getting removed when i click the second one, if if i send you the full source files, will you able to look at the issue.

Comment: @user1083175, I checked it with the sources of your demo, and it works for me. Not sure how else I can help.

Comment: $('.selected').data('maphilight', {alwaysOn: false}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
is this the only code you change, did you see there is 2 jquery functions under the previous code you given me, do you think those make issue in my code

Comment: This is strange i don't whay it's not working with me, any way thanks a lot taking time for resolve this issue.

Comment: dear socha, it's working i have changed the following code $('#shop1').data('maphilight', data,{alwaysOn: false}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');, it's working fine when you click the map, but if you click the list below, it, not it hilighting as before.

Comment: add the same line to the click handlers of the links in your list

Answer (score 0):

Changed a bit the code shown on previous answer so it is more generic:

```
// Init
$('.map').maphilight({
       stroke: false,               
}); 

// Reset all map

$('.selected').data('maphilight', {alwaysOn:false}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight'); 

$('area').click(function(){    
    // Reset all areas with class 'selected'
    $('.selected').data('maphilight', {alwaysOn: false}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    // Remove class selected
    $('area').removeClass('selected');
    // select and highlight this area
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).data('maphilight', {alwaysOn: true}).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
});
```