# How to change Image Map background color onClick event

Tags: jquery

Currently, I've found that image map background will be changed once mouse-over on it just like following link example

http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

What I want is I want to change image map background color once click on it. But I cannot find how to change map background onclick event. Any solution will be appreciate.

Comment: Hiya does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/J8wME/4/ and look here for sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729734/enabling-highlight-on-click-for-jquery-map-highlighting cheers!

Comment: can you post this comment as answer?

Comment: Sure :) 1 min please! Cheerios mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiya on @ppshien recommendation:

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/J8wME/4/

[Enabling Highlight On Click for jQuery Map Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729734/enabling-highlight-on-click-for-jquery-map-highlighting)

Thanks; and hope it helped! CHeers

Comment: Asking a little late, but the map region doesn't seem to highlight on click, on alert works in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make two areas at the same position with different colors. One have alwaysOn: true and other alwaysOn: false.

```
<area id="squareArea1" shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="#" alt="1" data-maphilight='{"alwaysOn":true,"stroke":false,"fillColor":"efb1a6","fillOpacity":"0.3"}'>
<area id="squareArea2" shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="#" alt="1" data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"efb1a6","fillOpacity":"0.8"}'>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bsmk/WnRy8/