# How to make an interactive map with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need a world map and be able to highlight portions of the map.

So when I execute (via js), `US`, it should highlight the US continent in the world map. Same goes for other countries. Any ideas where I should start / look?

I need a simple flat map. So nothing too sophisticated as to connecting to Google Map's API.

Have googled around and came across this: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html

http://ammap.com/ also looks interesting, but is in Flash. Would be great if there was a javascript version.

Any other alternatives worth mentioning?

Comment: amMap is pure JavaScript mapping library now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found [JQVMAP](http://jqvmap.com/) to be the best and easiest to integrate solution. Hope it helps!

Check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/fwgvp/show/embed), and the source [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/fwgvp/)

Comment: It is - from my experience faultless

Comment: Any idea how I can add 10 random dots on a country?

Comment: You can use jVectorMap for that. Here is a demo http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/. Jqvmap was derived from jVectorMap with some copyright violations. I would not recommend to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya here you go is this what you are looking for :) **demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/J8wME/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/J8wME/4/show/

Please let me know how it goes. Implementation is in Jquery and uses: (`Maphighlight`)

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
```

See my reply here as well:  [Enabling Highlight On Click for jQuery Map Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729734/enabling-highlight-on-click-for-jquery-map-highlighting)

Thanks; and hope it helped! CHeers